# FileUpload to SharePoint List Attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, file-upload

I have to attach a file to a SharePoint list item. I've already created a form with a File Upload control but I can't make it work! Can I have some help?

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://intradev"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    SPList app = web.Lists["projetoandre"];

                    SPListItemCollection collection = app.GetItems();

                    SPListItem item = collection.Add();
                    item["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
                    item["Data"] = Convert.ToString(txtDataPretendida.Text);
                    item["Banco"] = Convert.ToString(ddlBanco.Text);
                    item["Confirmação"] = Convert.ToString(rdlUrgencia.Text);

                    //Stream fs = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    //byte[] fileContents = new byte[fs.Length];
                    //fs.Read(fileContents, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                    //fs.Close();

                    SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
                    //string fileName = "Ficheiro_" + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
                    //attachments.Add(fileName, fileContents);

                    item.Update();

                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you!
Edit: By commenting those lines of code, I'm able to fill the list but of course, with no attachment!

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not being able to create a new item and attach a file to it.

Comment: Try commenting the file attachment part to see if the list item is created.. Let me know if that works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing might be because of SharePoint security. Try the following snippet:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://thiswebsite"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("/"))
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPList app = web.Lists["projetoandre"];

                SPListItemCollection collection = app.GetItems();

                SPListItem item = collection.Add();
                item["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;
                item["Data"] = Convert.ToString(txtDataPretendida.Text);
                item["Banco"] = Convert.ToString(ddlBanco.Text);
                item["Confirmação"] = Convert.ToString(rdlUrgencia.Text);

                if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
                {
                    Stream fs = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;
                    byte[] fileContents = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(fileContents, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                    fs.Close();

                    SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
                    string fileName = "Ficheiro_" + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
                    attachments.Add(fileName, fileContents);
                }

                item.Update();

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

In the user control file, add the following snippet after the end of `<ContentTemplate>` tag immediately before the closing of the `<asp:UpdatePanel>`:

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnSave" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled by the code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        Stream fs = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;

Comment: I'm going to try and I'll let you know!

Comment: The code works, it doesn't give any error but when I tried debugging, it is jumping the "if". It's not detecting the file on the FileUploadControl.

Comment: Did you check the list? Is the list item present there? And just check if the attachment is there, just in case?

Comment: Yes, the list item is there but not the attachment. I did the debug with block points and it was jumping the "if".

Comment: Have you used UpdatePanel? Can you share a snippet of the user control?

Comment: No, I didn't use UpdatePanel.

`<tr>
                            <td class="left-td">Arquivo:
                            </td>
                            <td class="right-td">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" />
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>`

Comment: Well, the root cause is `AllowMultiple`. That is included as part of .NET 4.5 and I'm guessing you are using SharePoint 2010 which is based on .NET 4.0. Remove that and you should be good.

Comment: Not working yet. It is doing the exact same thing, it is skiping the "if" and not attaching the file but still creating the item.

Comment: I sent my ascx code earlier if you want to check, I already tried to fix this countless times and I can't make the item get uploaded.

Comment: Just a quick question... is the file you uploaded empty? just read that empty files will return HasFile as false.. So add some test inside the file you tried to upload..

Comment: Yes, I know. I tried adding a .txt with texto on it and then an image. Both didn't work.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. All that mess for just a piece of code.